# How to integrate data from Ajax into chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, charts

I have the following problem. I would like to integrate the data, which I get from a `http` response into my `charts.js` charts.

I receive the data via `Ajax` from an api endpoint, which works fine. I also have a script for the `chart.js` charts. But I just cant combine these two scripts.

I currently dont know where and how to place the `Ajax` script. Should I copy it into the `charts-custom.js`? I have tried a couple of ways but it just wont work.

I have little experience with javascript and ajax.

I would appreciate very much if someone could look over my code and help me to integrate the ajax code with the `chart.js`

Thanks a lot and kind regards

I have to following files:

charts.html     --> all the html code
charts-custom.js  --> the javascript functions for the charts

```
var endpoint = '/algorithmicTrading/api/portfolioData/data/'

var chartData = []
var chartLabels = []

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){

        portfolioInstruments = data.portfolioInstruments
        absolutPositionValues = data.absolutPositionValues
        percentagePositionWeights = data.percentagePositionWeights


        setChart()
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

/*global $, document*/
$(document).ready(function setChart(data) {

    'use strict';

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#75787c';



    // ------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Bar Chart Custom 1
    // ------------------------------------------------------ //
    var BARCHART1 = $('#barChartCustom1');
    var barChartHome = new Chart(BARCHART1, {
        type: 'bar',
        options:
        {
            scales:
            {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    barPercentage: 0.2
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    display: false
                }],
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        data: {
            labels: portfolioInstruments,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Data Set 1",
                    backgroundColor: [
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99',
                        '#EF8C99'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 0.3,
                    data: absolutPositionValues
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

Comment: You seem really close, you should implement setChart(data) where it takes your ajax response and translates it to a format charts.js understands.  --- so that charts.js example you took, implement that in a new function called setChart.

Comment: thank you i have renamed the function but unfortunately it still does not work. Is it legit to paste the ajax script above the chart.js funtion?

Comment: So in javascript you can declare a function like `function setChart(data){}` and it pulls it to the top of the current `function(){}` it is inside. So to answer your question, yes, if the `setChart` function is OUTSIDE of the `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: Now, there is an exception to this, if you specify your function like `var setChart = function(data){};` then the variable `setChart` will be `undefined` until it reaches the line where it is specified.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dancameron/18ad7e46399406259323  --- Here is an example of someone doing what you want to do, although I don't like the way they declared their `invoice_status_data` variable... also jquery 3+ uses `.done` and `.fail` instead of "success" and "error"

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but I still dont know how to fix this. i have changed the initial post to the current state of the charts-custom.js. Could you pleaseee let me know what to change to get this running

Comment: I've posted an unfinished solution, mainly because I can't test your endpoint, but I've provided you with how I would start.

Comment: the endpoint can be found here http://165.227.152.128/algorithmicTrading/api/portfolioData/data/
what could i do for you if you would get this running ?

Comment: I've edited the code I posted, using a public MDN HTTPS API. I cannot call a HTTP endpoint from HTTPS (and neither can you!).  note: your chart should be a `canvas` note2: `$chart[0]` gets the DOM element, instead of a jquery object so that you can call `getContext` --- which is available on `canvas` elements.

Answer (score 3):

```js
'use strict';
var endpoint = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json'

function setChart(data){
    var portfolioInstruments = data.members.map(e=>e.name);
    var absolutPositionValues = data.members.map(e=>e.age);
    var percentagePositionWeights = data.percentagePositionWeights;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#75787c';
    // ------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Bar Chart Custom 1
    // ------------------------------------------------------ //
    var $chart = $('#barChartCustom1');
    var barChartHome = new Chart($chart[0].getContext("2d"), {
        type: 'bar',
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{ display: true, barPercentage: 0.2 }],
                yAxes: [{ ticks: { max: 100, min: 0 }, display: false }],
            },
            legend: { display: false }
        },
        data: {
            labels: portfolioInstruments,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Data Set 1",
                    backgroundColor: [  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99'],
                    borderColor: [  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99',  '#EF8C99'],
                    borderWidth: 0.3,
                    data: absolutPositionValues
                }
            ]
        }
    })
}

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        setChart(data);
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("Endpoint GET request error");
        // console.log(error_data)
    }
})

$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChartCustom1"></canvas>
```